# Restoring database in azure managed instance from one subscription to another

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, azure-managed-database

I have my production database in one subscription and dev/test database in other subscription. how can i restore database from production to test?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restoring to different subscription is not possible. Use copy_only [backup to URL](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/native-database-backup-in-azure-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/386154) option and restore it to another sqlmi instance. If service managed TDE is blocker then try [disabling](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-database/take-a-copy-only-backup-of-tde-protected-database-on-azure-sql/ba-p/643407) it or use customer managed [BYOK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/transparent-data-encryption-byok-azure-sql) TDE settings.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the database directly from the portal will not work involving two different subscriptions. It can be done in with Bacpac file as mentioned in this article.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5189/restore-an-azure-sql-database-from-one-server-to-another-server/

Comment: thank you. i will try to implement this method and will post if it worked for me or not

Comment: For anyone else arriving here looking for a solution for restoring a backup from a Managed Instance to a Managed Instance in different subscription, please note this answer is not targeting that scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can.
If you restore to a different subscription, the Create or Update v5.0.2022 API call that underlies the restore action must contain restorePointInTime, crossSubscriptionTargetManagedInstanceId, and either crossSubscriptionSourceDatabaseId or crossSubscriptionRestorableDroppedDatabaseId.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/point-in-time-restore?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#restore-to-a-different-subscription
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/point-in-time-restore?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-portal#restore-an-existing-database